# iOS 6 MKMapView Search for Places

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, mapkit

I want to search for places such as "Apple Store", "Italian Restaurant" etc. and also for address such as "5th Ave, New York, NY, United States".

How can I search for places and set MKPlacemark for each place I find?

Comment: I can retrieve data from google api but I couldn't retrieve places and it has requests limit. I want to use iOS 6 MapKit to search for address and places

Comment: MapKit does not provide this, you need get data yourself, then place map objects ...

Comment: Be careful about getting Google data and placing it on non-Google maps. It;s against their license agreement.

Comment: Hi jkigel, can you please tell me what solution you have used for getting places information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about requests limit for Google Maps API, you can use some of open source maps API instead perhaps, like Nominatim API , look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 6.1 Apple introduced a new search API - `MKLocalSearch`. You create a `MKLocalSearchRequest` using string and region to search in (the region is just a hint for the search, it doesn't guarantee results will fall within this region) and use this request to initialise a `MKLocalSearch`, which asynchronously gives you the results in an `MKLocalSearchResponse` object. It was only introduced in january, so it has it's issues at this stage - you only ever get 10 results per search, plus some of the results are strange, but it's definitely worth checking out. There's also no way to specify the type of object (town/business/landmark etc.) you're searching for, which is a shame. Here's a cool [tutorial](http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/01/28/mklocalsearch-example). Note that the more precise the region you supply the better the results.